# Minecraft commands: server log in titles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to write a command that will display a title that says "welcome" when you log into my server, but only on the screen of the player that just logged in. I want this to happen every time anyone logs into my server. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a Message Of The Day. This is text shown to users when they log in. Edit your *server.properties* to contain the following line:

```
motd=welcome
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He means using the /title command on a player when he joined the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to take the simple approach of just using a message of the day, this is doable with only 4 command blocks.

Set up a scoreboard objective to track, ironically, when a player leaves:

```
/scoreboard objectives add left stat.leaveGame
```

First two command blocks are for a [20Hz fill clock](http://moesh.ca/clocks-in-minecraft-1-8/).

Next command block is to actually display the title:

```
title @a[score_left_min=0] title Welcome!
```

And the final command block resets the scoreboard objective of all players:

```
scoreboard players set @a left -1
```

I'm setting the objective to -1 because I think that will catch everyone, regardless of if they've logged in before, but I can't test that, so it might not work the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is just a normal server without plugins and is not a bukkit server,doing this with command blocks is from hard to impossible.So I recommand finding plugins that can able to tell players upon log in "Welcome" and to set up a bukkit server.

Here is a video: